# Character appears like white box when calling method DrawString

Tags: c#, .net, gdi

I have a great question for you. I searched all the Google and MSDN and didn't find anything.

I'm trying to do a program that exports a font to single PNG images per character. I'm currently testing it with new Windows font, **Segoe UI Symbol**. Please note I know the font license terms and I won't distribute that font in the internet.

Well, the real problem is happening when I call the method `DrawString`, member of `Graphics`. I convert the unicode integer value to a char then to a string. I already tried to convert the integer to char with `char.ConvertFromUtf32()` and with `Convert.ToChar()`.

The program is working good during 26 characters (starting from **57344** = **0xE000**), the problem doesn't appear when I use numeric values until **57370**. After this, there is not a single number that is not written with a white box char.

After some search, I found an overload to `Font` constructor, with the attribute `gdiCharset` and tried to use its value as 2, but nothing was happened.

I'm showing the source code for you below. Please, if there is someone who can help me, I will be happy.

**UPDATE**
When I use escape sequences (like `"\uE1FF"` instead of char conversion it works! But I don't know how to make escape sequences within a for loop.

```
        Font segoe = new Font("Segoe UI Symbol", 800, FontStyle.Regular, GraphicsUnit.Pixel, 2);

        Bitmap bmedidor = new Bitmap(1000, 1000, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
        Graphics gmedidor = Graphics.FromImage(bmedidor);
        // This line below doesn't matter, see the method DrawString
        Size tamanho = gmedidor.MeasureString(char.ConvertFromUtf32(57344).ToString(), segoe).ToSize();

        int[] reducoes = new int[6] {512, 256, 128, 64, 32, 16};
        string caminho = "C:\\InoMetro";


        for (int u = 57344; u < 57896; u++)
        {
            Bitmap caractere = new Bitmap(tamanho.Width, tamanho.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
            Graphics criador = Graphics.FromImage(caractere);

            criador.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
            criador.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
            criador.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
            criador.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

            // Here we have the problem
            criador.DrawString(Convert.ToChar(u).ToString(), segoe, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), new PointF(0, 0));

            for (int r = 0; r < reducoes.Length; r++)
            {
                int taR = reducoes[r];

                Bitmap reducao = new Bitmap(taR, taR, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
                Graphics redutor = Graphics.FromImage(reducao);

                redutor.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                redutor.PixelOffsetMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
                redutor.CompositingQuality = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
                redutor.SmoothingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;

                redutor.DrawImage(caractere, 0, 0, taR, taR);
                reducao.Save(caminho + "\\" + taR.ToString() + "\\" + u.ToString() + ".png", System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png);

            }

        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

U+E000-U+F8FF (57344-63743 decimal) are [Private Use Area characters](http://www.unicode.org/charts/PDF/UE000.pdf).

Most fonts (including Segoe UI Symbol) don't provide glyphs for any code points in this range, so the typical fallback behavior is for the font renderer to display a white box () or a question mark in a black diamond (�) when asked to draw one of these code points.

Segoe UI Symbol on Windows 8 only defines glyphs for U+E000-U+E019, then provides no glyphs for U+E01A-U+E051; that's why white boxes are displayed for 57370 (0xE01A) through 57425 (0xE051).

Comment: I get a white box for every code point in that range on my system (Windows 7 SP1 x64). Does `charmap` on your system show that Segoe UI Symbol has glyphs for code points in that range?

Comment: The most likely explanation (I can't test right now) is that the version of Segoe UI Symbol included with Windows 8 contains 26 private use characters (at U+E000-U+E01A). For any other code points, a white box will be displayed, because the font doesn't contain those characters. What were you expecting instead?

Comment: I'm sorry, I think I was not clear to explain... I have glyphs until the char U+F013 in my font version but when written with GDI, it only works until 57370.

Comment: On Windows 8, Segoe UI Symbol contains glyphs for U+E000-U+E019, U+E052, U+E070-U+E072, U+E07D-U+E1EB, U+E200-E236, and so on. The defined glyphs are not contiguous and there are plenty of code points that don't have glyphs. (There are no glyphs between U+E026A-U+F005, for example.) Specifically, in response to your question, U+E01A-U+E051 (57370-57425 decimal) do not have glyphs and will display as white boxes in your program.

Comment: So, I think I didn't expect the loop to export all the characters. I will try to export all the loop and choose your best answer :) Anyway, thank you.

Comment: That is right, I tried again expecting the loop until it completes and it worked for all symbols I wanted, only including the white boxes I will delete. It was a silly problem... Thank you very much, and, if you think I deserve, please plus one my question.